# How to display hours in Y-axis of CFChart

Tags: coldfusion, cfchart

I would like to show hours in the Y-axis of a CFChart. Presently it is showing numeric values. I want the Y-axis to display `6am`, `9am`, `12noon`, `3pm` etc.. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you using ACF or Railo or OBD?. Do specify the version too.

Comment: From where are these numeric values coming?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [link](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2010/8/10/Ask-a-Jedi-Modify-cfchart-to-remove-commas-from-yaxis)

You have to pattern your y-axis. You need to create a style of the chart and assign pattern to your yaxis.

```
<CFCHART style="MyFirstDate.xml" .....>
    <CFCHARTSERIES type="line" 
              query=qGetValsByDate 
              itemColumn="xxxx" 
              valueColumn="thedate" 
              dataLabelStyle="none"/>
</CFCHART>
```

Paste the following into a file and save it as "MyFirstDate.xml".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<frameChart is3D="false">    
 <yAxis type="DateTime" isBucketed="true">
  <labelFormat style="DateTimePattern" pattern="h:mm tt"/>
  <parseFormat style="DateTimePattern" pattern="h:mm tt"/>
  <dateTimeStyle majorUnit="Hour" minorUnit="Hour" minorStep="2"/>
  <labelStyle isMultiline="false" isHideOverlapped="true" orientation="Vertical"/>
 </yAxis>    
</frameChart>
```

I haven't tested the code but I did similar to it so it will work. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

The CFChart included in ColdFusion 10 is Zingchart version 120315.
More recent versions of ZingChart have this json parameter

```
"scale-y": {
    "format": "javascript:formatScaleY"
}
```

then write a function like

```
formatScaleY(v) {
    return v+"am";
}
```

You can download a more recent zingchart library from their website and overwrite cfchart-min.js, but i'm not sure whether that is allowed by the CF/ZC license.